# c# enable audio setting "listen to this device" in system control

Tags: c#, audio, naudio

My program is using NAudio and I want that all mic recorded sounds are send directly to the speaker. In the window system control -> sound -> recording -> Properties i can click of the second tab "Listen" and then "Listen to this device"

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lx0zq.png)

How can this be done in C#? I have no idea what the right search words to find an example

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is nothing available in the Windows APIs to toggle this setting.
You can find a discussion about this in the following support article:
[Access to the "Listen to this device" setting](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Windowsapps/en-US/f243f5e2-c2ac-4cec-8f57-0825cab48af5/access-to-the-quotlisten-to-this-devicequot-setting?forum=windowspro-audiodevelopment)

Since you are already using NAudio, you can try to copy the microphone stream to a playback device within your own application.
This article should help you achieve that:
[How to record and play audio at the same time with NAudio](https://markheath.net/post/how-to-record-and-play-audio-at-same)

Comment: Yeah I know this article but the problem is that at the first 10 seconds the sound is not clear that way. When I have a constante sound like a whistle the sound as silence parts in it. Just as if you have a bad cell phone connection and can hear only second word.

Comment: Can you determine if the audio is dropping out or just pausing momentarily? It could be a different problem depending on whether the sounds made during the silence is dropped or delayed.
Dropping audio is when the buffers are being skipped or copied incorrectly. Pausing audio is usually a performance issue that could be related to other parts of the application or your PC.

Comment: How can I found this out? I once was asking this already here with the silence in the recorded sound [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53847245/unwanted-silence-parts-in-naudio-recording) unfortunately I didn't understand what Mark was suggesting so I could make it work. That's why I looked for an alternative

Comment: Speaking a sentence into the mic while playing it back should give you an idea of whether the silence is replacing parts of the words spoken or if the silence is splitting the words up. -- However, Mark's answer in that other question might be the correct solution. You are using a SavingWaveProvider inbetween the BufferedWaveProvider and the WaveOut, just use the BufferedWaveProvider directly in player.Init() and see if that works. I wish I could comment on that thread directly though.

Comment: Your linked question seems to be a duplicate of this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15101889/hearing-the-incoming-audio-from-mic

Answer (score 0):

Since there does not seem to be a public API that achieves this I will point to a public API which may be functionally similar to what you effectively want to achieve if that is quickly toggling the the passthrough of the microphone audio for listening to the microphone and quickly muting it.

[WM-Appcommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-appcommand) APPCOMMAND_MICROPHONE_VOLUME_MUTE

Unfortunately the recording ability will also be muted.

The effect can be seen in the Levels tab which is right next to the Listen tab in the control panel.

To be effective "listen to this device" will have to be enabled already.

This is not C# directly but is invoking win32 dlls via C#.

```
private const uint APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP = 24;
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessageW(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
SendMessageW(this.Handle, WmAppcommand, this.Handle, (IntPtr)APPCOMMAND_MICROPHONE_VOLUME_MUTE;
```